# rspec: how to test ssh.scp

Tags: ruby, rspec, net-ssh

I have the following ruby code that I'm trying to test using rspec.

```
begin
Net::SSH.start(server_ip, server_username, :password => server_password) do |ssh|
    ssh.scp.upload!(local_file, remote_file)
    ssh.exec!("some command")
    ... more ssh.exec!
end
rescue
    puts "Failed to SSH"
end
```

and my rspec looks like:

```
ssh_mock = double

expect(SSH).to receive(:start).and_yield(ssh_mock)
expect(ssh_mock).to receive(:scp)
expect(ssh_mock).to receive(:exec!).with("some command")
```

The problem is that the test never passes because it jumps to rescue when it reaches the scp and the scp.upload is never tested properly.

So, is there a way to test scp.upload when it is called in way similar to this example?

So far, the only way I was able to test the SCP is by having a separate block. exp

```
Net::SCP.start(server_ip, server_username, :password => server_password) do |scp|
    scp.upload!(local_file, remote_file)
end
```

But can I test it without having to separate the SCP from SSH just like the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should also mock the `scp` returned from `ssh.scp`, something like this:

```
ssh_mock = double
scp_mock = double('scp')

expect(SSH).to receive(:start).and_yield(ssh_mock)
expect(ssh_mock).to receive(:scp).and_return(scp_mock)
expect(scp_mock).to receive(:upload!).with(local_file, remote_file)
expect(ssh_mock).to receive(:exec!).with("some command")
```